# Find exact solutions of poisson equation at grid points

Tags: partial-differential-equations, poissons-equation

I have a question about discretization of 2-D Poisson. For an equation such as $\Delta u=sin(x,y)$, all boundary conditions are given like $u ( x , 0 ) = u ( x , \pi ) =$$u ( 0 , y ) = u ( \pi , y ) = 0$. If we discretize it in the domain, is there a way to obtain exact solution at grid points(like exact solution at u(1,1))?

Any help would be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's a discretization, so no.

Comment: You can find the approximate solution at a grid of points using Finite Difference techniques, for example. You could also just solve the PDE analytically and evaluate it at your grid of points. Up to you!

Comment: Any idea how to solve it analytically? Sorry I'm new to this area.